# A type-safe way to recursively map a class to its JSON representation

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm trying to implement an interface called `Serialised<T>` to represent recursive serialisation of public non-function properties of a given class.

My [current implementation](https://github.com/jan-molak/tiny-types/blob/db9cb3d14c90dc2434251cf6d54445222825ec5a/src/types/serialisation.ts) uses [type-level programming](https://github.com/jan-molak/tiny-types/blob/master/src/types/lookup.ts) and works with TypeScript 3.0, but it feels like it could be simplified to take advantage of the new language features in TS 3.3 and don't smell of a hack.

## The mechanics

Assume that we already have a base class called `TinyType` with a method [`toJSON`](https://github.com/jan-molak/tiny-types/blob/db9cb3d14c90dc2434251cf6d54445222825ec5a/src/TinyType.ts#L124).

The method serialises any subclasses of `TinyType` according to the following rules, which I'd like the `Serialised<T>` interface to represent, so that the child class could be defined as:

```js
class MyClass extends TinyType {
    toJSON(): Serialised<MyClass> {...}
}
```

### Example 1 - primitive value wrapper

When a TinyType wraps a single value, it's serialised to whatever that single value would be serialised to.

For primitives, the serialised representation of a `TinyType` is the primitive itself:

```js
class Name extends TinyType {
    constructor(public readonly name: string) {}
}

new Name('Bob').toJSON() === 'Bob';   // toJSON(): string


class Age extends TinyType {
    constructor(public readonly age: string) {}
}

new Age(42).toJSON() === 42 .         // toJSON(): number
```

### Example 2 - TinyType wrapper

However, we could also be in a situation where a single-value TinyType wraps another single-value TinyType, in which case rules from the first example apply recursively:

```js
class Integer extends TinyType {
    constructor(public readonly value: number) {
      // some logic that ensures that value is an integer...
    }
}

class AmountInCents extends TinyType {
    constructor(public readonly amountInCents: Integer) {}
}

class Credit extends TinyType {
    constructor(public readonly amount: AmountInCents) {}
}

new Credit(new AmountInCents(new Integer(100))).toJSON() === 100
// toJSON(): number
```

### Example 3: multi-value wrapper

When a TinyType wraps several values, it should be serialised to a JSON object with keys representing public non-function properties of the TinyType and values representing their serialised versions.

```js
class Timestamp extends TinyType {
    constructor(public readonly value: Integer) {}
}

class Credit extends TinyType {
    constructor(public readonly amount: AmountInCents) {}
}

class CreditRecorded extends TinyType {
    constructor(
        public readonly credit: Credit,
        public readonly timestamp: Timestamp,
    ) {}        
}

new CreditRecorded(
  new Credit(new AmountInCents(new Integer(100))),
  new Timestamp(new Integer(1234567)),
).toJSON() === { credit: 100, timestamp: 1234567 }
```

My research so far shows that the solution could take advantage of:

- [Conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html)
- [Type inference](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21496)

I could of course define `toJSON()` as returning [`JSONValue`](https://github.com/jan-molak/tiny-types/blob/db9cb3d14c90dc2434251cf6d54445222825ec5a/src/types/json.ts) and avoid the whole trouble of mapping the class to its serialised representation, but it feels like a better job could be done here?

Thoughts and suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work as expected:

```
type NotFunctions<T, E extends keyof T> = {
    [P in Exclude<keyof T, E>]-?: T[P] extends Function ? never : P
}[Exclude<keyof T, E>]

type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
    (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never

type Unwrap<T> = T extends { toJSON(): infer U } ? U : T;
type PickAndUnwrap<T, K extends keyof T> = {
    [P in K] : Unwrap<T[P]>
}

type SimpleOrComplex<T, E extends keyof T> =  NotFunctions<T, E> extends UnionToIntersection<NotFunctions<T, E>>?
    PickAndUnwrap<T, NotFunctions<T, E>>[NotFunctions<T, E>] :
    PickAndUnwrap<T, NotFunctions<T, E>>

type Id<T> = T extends object ? {} & { [P in keyof T] : T[P]} : T

class TinyType {
    public toJSON(): Id<SimpleOrComplex< this, keyof TinyType>> {
        return null!;
    }
}

class Name extends TinyType {
    constructor(public readonly name: string) {
        super();
    }
}

new Name('Bob').toJSON() === "" // toJSON(): string


class Age extends TinyType {
    constructor(public readonly age: number) {
        super()
    }
}

new Age(42).toJSON() === 42          // toJSON(): number

class Integer extends TinyType {
    constructor(public readonly value: number) {
        super();
    }
}

class AmountInCents extends TinyType {
    constructor(public readonly amountInCents: Integer) {
        super();
    }
}

class Credit extends TinyType {
    constructor(public readonly amount: AmountInCents) {
        super()
    }
}
new AmountInCents(new Integer(100)).toJSON
new Credit(new AmountInCents(new Integer(100))).toJSON() === 100
// toJSON(): number

class Timestamp extends TinyType {
    constructor(public readonly value: Integer) {
        super();
    }
}


class CreditRecorded extends TinyType {
    constructor(
        public readonly credit: Credit,
        public readonly timestamp: Timestamp,
    ) {
        super();
    }        
}

new CreditRecorded(
  new Credit(new AmountInCents(new Integer(100))),
  new Timestamp(new Integer(1234567)),
).toJSON() === { credit: 100, timestamp: 1234567 }

class Person extends TinyType {
    constructor(
        public readonly name: Name,
        public readonly creditRecord: CreditRecorded,
        public readonly age: Integer) {
        super();
    }
}

new Person(new Name(""), new CreditRecorded(
  new Credit(new AmountInCents(new Integer(100))),
  new Timestamp(new Integer(1234567)),
), new Integer(23)).toJSON() // { readonly name: string; readonly creditRecord: { readonly credit: number; readonly timestamp: number; }; readonly age: number; }
```

Just a few caveats, did not test extensively, so you might get `any` at some depth if the compiler decides the type is too complex. `Id` is just there for cosmetic reason to flatten out the type, if you run into issue just use `Id<T> = T` and see if taht fixes it.

If you have any questions let me know and I will try to answer, the solution is mostly just a straight up application of mapped and conditional types like you thought it would be.

Comment: The peoples champion.

Comment: @ShanonJackson  I try 

Comment: This works perfectly with simple types such as:

    const value: number = new Integer(1234567).toJSON()

as well as nested simple types:

    const value: number = new Timestamp(new Integer(1234567)).toJSON()

However, it doesn't seem to work with complex types. This one is correct:

    const c: { credit: number, timestamp: number } = new CreditRecorded(
        new Credit(new AmountInCents(new Integer(123))),
        new Timestamp(new Integer(123))
    ).toJSON();

But this one should not be:
    
    const c: string = new CreditRecorded(...).toJSON();

Thoughts?

Comment: @JanMolak I get an error on the last assignment. Maybe if you can provide a small repo that shows the issue?\ We can talk more on https://gitter.im/ if you need more help with this

Comment: Sorry, I see what's going on. I was experimenting with your code sample in IntelliJ's "scratches", where IntelliJ did not highlight the error. However, if I do it in a regular file the last assignment is correctly flagged as invalid. Thanks for your help, I've just learnt something new about IntelliJ :-)